# prove, $Z_4$ is a normal subgroup of eight-element group

Tags: proof-writing, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I have problems to prove this:

There is an eight-element group $G$ that has a subgroup H that is isomorphic to $Z_4$. Prove, that H is a normal subgroup of G.

I have never done this before, so I do not know which facts do I need. But I know, that due to the isomorphism of H is H cyclic and commutative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The two answers interpret your question in two different ways. The one answers "There exists a group $G$ of order $8$ such that $Z_4$ is a normal subgroup." The other answers "For every group $G$ that has a normal subgroup isomorphic  to $Z_4$ this subgroup is normal." You should clarify via an [edit] what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* More generally, every subgroup of index $2$ is normal.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that I understand, you're being asked to find $G$ such that $G$ has order $8$ and has a normal subgroup isomorphic to $Z_4$?

One easy way to do this is to note that if $H, K$ are any groups then $H$ is normal in $H \times K$ and $|H \times K| = |H|\cdot|K|$.  So let $H = Z_4$ and choose $K$ to have the right order.